# Python keeps on showing 'EXPRESSION EXPECTED ' in the elif commands in so many different lines like 46th, 54th, 62nd, and so on

Tags: google-colaboratory

```
#Program 9-3
#Menu driven program to do various list operations
myList = [22,4,16,38,13] #myList already has 5 elements
choice = 0
while True:
 print("The list 'myList' has the following elements", myList)
 print("\nL I S T O P E R A T I O N S")
 print(" 1. Append an element")
 print(" 2. Insert an element at the desired position")
 print(" 3. Append a list to the given list")
 print(" 4. Modify an existing element")
 print(" 5. Delete an existing element by its position")
 print(" 6. Delete an existing element by its value")
 print(" 7. Sort the list in ascending order")
 print(" 8. Sort the list in descending order")
 print(" 9. Display the list")
 print(" 10. Exit")
 choice = int(input("ENTER YOUR CHOICE (1-10): "))
 #append element
 if choice == 1:
   element = int(input("Enter the element to be appended: "))
   myList.append(element)
   print("The element has been appended\n")
   #insert an element at desired position
 elif choice == 2:
   element = int(input("Enter the element to be inserted: "))
   pos = int(input("Enter the position:"))
   myList.insert(pos,element)
   print("The element has been inserted\n")
   #append a list to the given list
 elif choice == 3:
   newList = eval(input( "Enter the elements separated by commas"))
   myList.extend(list(newList))
   print("The list has been appended\n")
   #modify an existing element
 elif choice == 4:
   i = int(input("Enter the position of the element to be modified: "))
 if i < len(myList):
   newElement = int(input("Enter the new element: "))
   oldElement = myList[i]
   myList[i] = newElement
   print("The element",oldElement,"has been modified\n")
 else:
   print("Position of the element is more than the length of list")
   #delete an existing element by position
 elif choice == 5:
   i = int(input("Enter the position of the element to be deleted: "))
if i < len(myList):
     element = myList.pop(i)
     print("The element",element,"has been deleted\n")
else:
   print("\nPosition of the element is more than the length of list")
   #delete an existing element by value
 elif choice == 6:
   element = int(input("\nEnter the element to be deleted: "))
   if element in myList:
     myList.remove(element)
     print("\nThe element",element,"has been deleted\n")
   else:
    print("\nElement",element,"is not present in the list")
       #list in sorted order
   elif choice == 7:
     myList.sort()
     print("\nThe list has been sorted")
 #list in reverse sorted order
  elif choice == 8:
    myList.sort(reverse = True)
     print("\nThe list has been sorted in reverse order")
 #display the list
   elif choice == 9:
 print("\nThe list is:", myList)
 #exit from the menu
   elif choice == 10:
     break
   else:
     print("Choice is not valid")
     print("\n\nPress any key to continue..............")
     ch = input()
```

I was trying to write a menu driven program to perform various list operations, such as:

- Append an element
- Inser an element
- Modify an existed element
- Delete an existing element from its position
- Delete an existing element with a given value
- Sort the list in ascending order.
- Sort the list in descending order.
- Display the list